# Installing Apache Web Server from OSGeo4W

Tags: qgis, installation, osgeo4w, apache

I am trying to create a QGIS web client on my Windows 8 But with OSGEO4W not appear the option to make Apache installs Web Server, as of this writing in several tutorials and documentations.

A print screen of my Windows 8

[image]

Should this well, this print belongs to a tutorial found on the web

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, Apache is not bundled with the 64-bit OSGeo4W installer.

You can still select qgis-server from the Web category in the 64-bit installer though, so you should do that.

But you would probably have to grab the 32-bit OSGeo4W installer and install Apache from there instead.

Or install httpd Apache from http://httpd.apache.org/ and enable any needed modules or dependencies to run qgis-server through it like mod_fastcgi and php for apache https://www.php.net/

Here are some of the mod_fastcgi configuration options too http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html

Comment: It might be better to install QGIS for 32 bit too, because the 32-bit version goes into a different installing folder than the 64-bit.