# QGIS web server on Windows 7

Tags: qgis

I have followed @underdark instructions but I fail in one respect!  When I go to the OSGeo4W installer and select Advanced Install>Select Packages>Web I don't have the option for installing Apache as it's missing from the list - I'm now down the end of a blind alley with no idea how to proceed - can anyone help?
[image: screenshot of my 'Select Packages' options]

Comment: I think a very similar question was asked here: [How to install Apache Web Server from OSGeo4W?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111204/how-to-install-apache-web-server-from-osgeo4w).

Answer (score 1):

Take a 32bit version of OSGeo4W installer. There is no apache in 64bit installer.